# Rails - how to validate f.select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, select

I have simple `select` field

```
f.select(:name, [["- Choose Name -", 0]] + People.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })
```

How can I validate, if some name was selected?
I tried this rule:

```
  validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'Name cannot be blank.'}
```

But if I send form without choosing the name, the form is sent...

So I would like to ask you, how can I validate the select field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, people *are* selecting a name, they're selecting the name `- Choose Name -` with id `0`.

If you want to give an option that doesn't correspond to a real choice then you have two options:

```
f.select(:name, People.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }, :include_blank => "- Choose Name -")

f.select(:name, People.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }, :prompt => "- Choose Name -")
```

These are basically identical. Both will display an option at the top of the select which won't result in a value being set. However, the `prompt` version will only display this extra option if there isn't a current value selected, i.e. if used on an edit form it won't let the user clear their selection by setting it back to nil

Note that the `include_blank` method is very similar to the following code, except lots more readable:

```
f.select(:name, [["- Choose Name -", nil]] + People.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })
```

Comment: Use pluck over map, `People.pluck(:name, :id)`

Comment: Great point. I was focusing on the bit of the code that directly answered OP's question, but that's a very useful thing to know too